# iPhone XS Max stuck in bootloop, cannot get into recovery

Tags: iphone, startup

This issue started with a message saying that my storage space was almost full. I open settings and check storage, the estimate size does not show up. I go to photos app to delete a few photos/videos. I select a bunch and hit on delete, the images do not delete and the phone reboots into the Apple Logo.

It's been stuck on the apple logo boot loop for a while now.

Unable to set the iPhone to recovery mode by holding VOL UP + VOL DOWN + Power Button for 10 seconds.

Plugging the iPhone into my Macbook does not show the device connected.

What should I do next?

iPhone Model - iPhone XS Max 256GB

iOS Version - 14.4

Comment: Have you tried contacting Apple Support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this honestly sounds like your device's drive got corrupted entirely. you'd be better to send it to Apple for repair, i don't think there's anything an end-user can do without voiding any warranties or whatnot at best, destroying the device accidentally at worst.

Answer (score -1):

> Unable to set the iPhone to recovery mode by holding VOL UP + VOL DOWN + Power Button for 10 seconds.

That is **not** the button combination used to enter recovery mode.

With the iPhone connected to the computer via a Lightning cable, recovery mode is achieved by:

1. Briefly pressing volume up
2. Briefly pressing volume down
3. Holding the sleep/wake button until the iPhone reboots

This can take more than 10 seconds; don’t let go of the sleep/wake button at step 3 until a good 15-20 seconds passes.

A video showing how to *correctly* enter recovery mode on iPhone 8/X and newer: https://youtu.be/a70jiFqMGX0

Comment: Unable to enter recovery mode with this combination as mentioned in my post.

Comment: Sorry, the way you worded it made it sound like you tried “holding VOL UP + VOL DOWN + Power Button for 10 seconds”.

Comment: @JashJacob Have you tried contacting Apple Support?

Comment: Yes, I gave the device to apple support for service.